# Accessing Spring-Boot Service in Docker Container from browser

Tags: spring-boot, docker

I have a very simple Spring Boot service that has no authorisation, and should bypass CORS :

```
@RestController
public class MyController {

    @CrossOrigin
    @GetMapping(value = "/test")
    public String test() {
        return "hello";
    }
```

I then run this in a docker container

If I do **docker ps -a** this is what I see :

[image]

I assume that if I want to call my /test service then all I would have to do is :

> http://localhost:8080/test

I have also tried :

```
http://localhost:9090/test 
http://localhost:90/test
http://0.0.0.0:9090/test
```

But I get nothing.

Is there some issue with my ports?

Comment: If you use docker toolbox under windows You use the IP shown with the `docker-env` command. 127.0.0.1/localhost doesn't belong to your docker. Your docker machine runs under such linux VM and the IP shown via `docker-env` is the default IP of the VM. To particularly map it to localhost you can set it up through the virtualbox then do some port forwarding as shown on the <a href="https://www.jhipster.tech/tips/020_tip_using_docker_containers_as_localhost_on_mac_and_windows.html"> Using Docker containers as localhost on Mac/Windows</a> article

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like an issue with port exposing.
If you just want to expose the same port 8080 you could use the following command

```
--publish 8080:8080
```

It is enough to be accessible via the browser.

But the issue may also be with your application, so you can try to connect to it via an interactive terminal (i.e. not in detached mode) to see logs output:

```
docker run --interactive --tty --name shape-shop-back-end --publish 8080:8080 shape-shop-back-end_app-server
```

Answer (score 1):

1. make sure that the port of your spring boot application is **8080** (by default it is 8080, but can be overriden in application.properties or application.yml)
2. make sure that you run docker container with the following command:

   docker run -it -p**8080:8080** **image_name:image_version**

where **image_name** and **image_version** correspond to the image you build or pull from docker hub

3. make sure that no other applicaiton is running on port **8080** (it could be any process, which is left running after incorrect shut down. On Windows I usually go to the process manager and shut down all running jvms, or you can use special tools to find id of the process, which runs on **8080** and shut it down). According to your screenshot, it doesn't look like there is a docker process running on **8080**, but it can be any other process, so I wouldn't exclude this possibility.

Answer (score 1):

I do not see any issue in your attached screenshot. I do not feel it's a port issue.

Are your sure the request reaching to your rest application. Can you try to check the application log inside your docker container and see if the request is reaching there?